# magento 2 : how to display product name in cart according to store view(English/Arabic)

Tags: product, checkout, magento2.3, cart

In the current scenario when the user adds a product from the English view on the cart page it displays product English name and when I switch the store from English to Arabic product name still coming in English even on the backend I have saved Arabic for that product name for Arabic store view.

Now I want to display product name in cart according to store view if store view is English product name should be in English and if the store view is Arabic product name should be in Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **store->Attributes->product->search name-> edit-> Advanced Attribute Properties->scope**
change it global to **storeview** wise

After changing this setting run php bin/magento index:reindex and check

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set individually under store view. This would save your data in `core_config_data` store and website wise.

Thnx

Comment: Yes I add a name for English and for Arabic Store vIew as well

Comment: So, just select those and then do your thing, then see.

Comment: @AliSultanKhan I'm hoping you tried the reindexing too.

Answer (score 1):

I could replicate this issue on a custom theme but not in Luma Theme.

Try changing your theme to Luma Theme and see if this still happens. If the product name is 
changing accordingly in Luma Theme, then it probably is caused by your custom theme.